# Unable to read the attributes of child nodes using XML DOM in Access 2003

Tags: xml, ms-access, xml-parsing, vba

I have searched the web for perhaps 8 hours including Experts Exchange and Stackoverflow and have found others with the same issue but I've not found a solution to this issue.

I'm attaching an XML file which uses Attributes to store the data in a parent node and three dependent child nodes.  All of the Attributes are uniquely named.  the XML opens in all browsers and I'm fairly certain that it is "well-formed".  I have successfully written code to read the attributes of the parent node but every time I attempt to write code to read the attributes of the child nodes, I get a run time error 91 or no error at all.

```
<Donors>
    <Donor DonorID="34224" Email="tsmith@gmail.com" DonorFirstName="Tom" DonorMiddleName="" DonorLastName="Smith" DonorAddress1="2052 Main Street" DonorAddress2="" DonorCity="New York" DonorStateProv="New York" DonorPostalCode="10019" DonorPhoneHome="2125298624" DonorPhoneWork="" DonorPhoneWorkExt="" DonorPhoneMobile="" DonorEmailAlternate="">
        <PageTypes>
              <PageType OnlinePageType="Product Purchase" /> 
        </PageTypes>
        <Transaction>
             <Transactions TransactionID="194" CCTransactionID="-999" OrderTimeStamp="2013-05-24T07:16:37.333" OrderTotal="110.0000" /> 
        </Transaction>
        <Products>
            <Product ProductGroupName="First Pitch Tickets" ProductName="Single" ProductDescription="1 Ticket for $10" ClientCode="I000001351" ProductCount="1" TotalFees="0.0000" TotalAmount="10.0000" /> 
            <Product ProductGroupName="First Pitch Tickets" ProductName="12 Tickets" ProductDescription="12 tickets for $100" ClientCode="I000001352" ProductCount="1" TotalFees="0.0000" TotalAmount="100.0000" /> 
        </Products>
</Donor>
```

I've tried MANY permutations of the following code without success.  I welcome any suggestions on how to cycle through this XML so that I can process and store the data into two related tables.

```
Function ReadAttributes(ByVal strXML As String)

Dim xmldoc As New DOMDocument
Dim iNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim iNode2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim DonorNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim iAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim iAtt2 As IXMLDOMAttribute

On Error GoTo ReadAttributes_OnError

xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.loadXML strXML
If xmldoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid XML, Load Failed"
    GoTo ReadAttributes_OnError
End If

Set DonorNodeList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Donor")

For Each iNode In DonorNodeList
    For Each iAtt In iNode.Attributes
        MsgBox iAtt.Name & ": " & iAtt.nodeTypedValue
    Next
    Set iNode2 = iNode.firstChild
    MsgBox iNode2.nodeName
    For Each iAtt2 In iNode2.Attributes
        MsgBox iAtt.Name & ": " & iAtt.nodeTypedValue
    Next
Next
Exit Function

ReadAttributes_OnError:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Is there any reason answer is not yet accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

Always validate xml string when there is issue to parse it,

**[Verify Your XML Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp)**

Copy your string to know if its error free.

**Updated XML**

```
<Donors>
    <Donor DonorID="34224" Email="tsmith@gmail.com" DonorFirstName="Tom" DonorMiddleName="" DonorLastName="Smith" DonorAddress1="2052 Main Street" DonorAddress2="" DonorCity="New York" DonorStateProv="New York" DonorPostalCode="10019" DonorPhoneHome="2125298624" DonorPhoneWork="" DonorPhoneWorkExt="" DonorPhoneMobile="" DonorEmailAlternate="">
        <PageTypes>
              <PageType OnlinePageType="Product Purchase" /> 
        </PageTypes>
        <Transaction>
             <Transactions TransactionID="194" CCTransactionID="-999" OrderTimeStamp="2013-05-24T07:16:37.333" OrderTotal="110.0000" /> 
        </Transaction>
        <Products>
            <Product ProductGroupName="First Pitch Tickets" ProductName="Single" ProductDescription="1 Ticket for $10" ClientCode="I000001351" ProductCount="1" TotalFees="0.0000" TotalAmount="10.0000" /> 
            <Product ProductGroupName="First Pitch Tickets" ProductName="12 Tickets" ProductDescription="12 tickets for $100" ClientCode="I000001352" ProductCount="1" TotalFees="0.0000" TotalAmount="100.0000" /> 
        </Products>
    </Donor>
</Donors>
```

```
Function ReadAttributes(ByVal strXML As String)

    Dim xmldoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim iNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim iNode2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim DonorNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim iAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim iAtt2 As IXMLDOMAttribute

    On Error GoTo ReadAttributes_OnError

    xmldoc.async = False
    xmldoc.LoadXML strXML
    If xmldoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid XML, Load Failed"
        GoTo ReadAttributes_OnError
    End If

    Set DonorNodeList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Donor")

    For Each iNode In DonorNodeList
        For Each iAtt In iNode.Attributes
            MsgBox iAtt.Name & ": " & iAtt.nodeTypedValue
        Next


        Set iNode2 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Donor")(0)

        For i = 0 To iNode2.ChildNodes.Length - 1
            For Each iAtt In iNode2.ChildNodes(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes
                MsgBox iAtt.Name & ": " & iAtt.nodeTypedValue
            Next
        Next
    Next


    Exit Function

ReadAttributes_OnError:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Function
End Function
```