# XML Parse into excel

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2013, vba

I have been through about 20 examples of trying to parse xml into excel and none seem to work for my source. The big problem here is I dont know how to parse xml in excel VBA anyway.

Here are my questions:

1) Is there any online resource I could use to understand the MSXML reference libraries used in excel that you guys recommend?
2) Is there something malformed with the xml I am trying to parse? (see below for example xml)

The error messages often seem to have two themes.. either the example uses a variable thats not defined in MSXML v6 or it opens the xml but never finds a document element.

*** Updated: Sorry I should have said I am trying to get the message href, the subject heading, the date posted and the variable Kudos

```
<response status="success">
<node_message_context type="node_message_context">
<message type="message" href="/messages/id/25704">
<id type="int">25704</id>
<read_only type="boolean">false</read_only>
<message_rating type="float">0.0</message_rating>
<last_edit_author type="user" href="/users/id/1094">
<login type="string">AllenSmith</login>
</last_edit_author>
<kudos>
<count type="int">1</count>
</kudos>
<last_edit_time type="date_time">2013-06-26T13:23:44+00:00</last_edit_time>
<post_time type="date_time">2013-06-26T13:23:44+00:00</post_time>
<board type="board" href="/boards/id/DesktopAPI"/>
<subject type="string">
Re: SKYPE4COM MessageSta​tus received event doesn't fire all the times (skype window has or not focu
</subject>
<deleted type="boolean">false</deleted>
<author type="user" href="/users/id/1094">
<login type="string">AllenSmith</login>
</author>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/25696"/>
<root type="message" href="/messages/id/25696"/>
<board_id type="int">1331</board_id>
<parent type="message" href="/messages/id/25696"/>
<teaser type="string"/>
<views>
<count type="int">43</count>
</views>
</message>
<message type="message" href="/messages/id/25690">
<id type="int">25690</id>
<read_only type="boolean">false</read_only>
<message_rating type="float">0.0</message_rating>
<last_edit_author type="user" href="/users/id/1094">
<login type="string">AllenSmith</login>
</last_edit_author>
<kudos>
<count type="int">0</count>
</kudos>
<last_edit_time type="date_time">2013-06-25T13:38:17+00:00</last_edit_time>
<post_time type="date_time">2013-06-25T13:38:17+00:00</post_time>
<board type="board" href="/boards/id/SkypeKitAPI"/>
<subject type="string">Re: Connection to the runtime was refused</subject>
<deleted type="boolean">false</deleted>
<author type="user" href="/users/id/1094">
<login type="string">AllenSmith</login>
</author>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/23414"/>
<root type="message" href="/messages/id/23414"/>
<board_id type="int">6977</board_id>
<parent type="message" href="/messages/id/23414"/>
<teaser type="string"/>
<views>
<count type="int">64</count>
</views>
</message>
```

Comment: Kindly refer this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783816/unable-to-read-the-attributes-of-child-nodes-using-xml-dom-in-access-2003/16798801#16798801)

Answer (score 0):

There are errors with your xml. I would suggest running this through a validation service such as http://www.xmlvalidation.com/, which will show you what needs to change to make this well formed xml.