# MSXML.DOMDocument how to configured VBA Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

In my project I am going to read XML file. I have read some document for it and tried  some sample code but I get error to this "MSXML.DOMDocument" VBA throw compile time error,

How should i configured "MSXML.DOMDocument" vba excel 2007

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783816/unable-to-read-the-attributes-of-child-nodes-using-xml-dom-in-access-2003/16798801#16798801) maybe helpful.

Comment: You can do late binding too ... something like `Set obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")` to avoid referencing all together. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047044/excel-vba-getting-specific-node-from-xml/) too

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference XML in your VBA Project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx