# Problems with .SelectNodes not returning any nodes

Tags: xml, vba

I have a problem with MSXML2.DOMDocument.SelectNodes function. My XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="PCVManifestReport http://ritenetdb-prod.aodc.slb.com/ReportServer?%2FRITENETReports%2FPCVManifestReport&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="PCVManifestReport" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="PCVManifestReport">
 <Tablix1>
   <Details_Collection>
     <Details Textbox24="CONTAINER" Serial_No="7345" Remarks="General transportation container.  Alternate codes are: Container, Container-Mini, Container-Modular, Container-Open, Container-Closed, Container-HalfHeight, Container-Food, Container-Box, Container-Skid, Basket, Pallet, Rack - Location to adjust Maintenance Events Certification Lifting, Cert-NDT etc as per Country/SLB standard applied." Item_Count="6" Transport_Index="234.60" Seal="" />
     <Details Textbox24="CONTAINER" Serial_No="28056-I" Remarks="General transportation container.  Alternate codes are: Container, Container-Mini, Container-Modular, Container-Open, Container-Closed, Container-HalfHeight, Container-Food, Container-Box, Container-Skid, Basket, Pallet, Rack - Location to adjust Maintenance Events Certification Lifting, Cert-NDT etc as per Country/SLB standard applied." Seal="" />
     <Details Textbox24="BUNKER" Serial_No="EXPS-SEW 14" Remarks="Explosive bunker used for wellsite storage and transport." Seal="" />
   </Details_Collection>
 </Tablix1>
 <Tablix2>
   <Details1_Collection>
     <Details1 Textbox60="">
       <Tablix3 Textbox40="CONTAINER,7345">
         <Details2_Collection>
           <Details2 Asset_Code="EQF-38" Serial_No1="38752" Remarks1="1-11/16 IN. DIA STEEL WEIGHT BAR, STD SERVICE. RATED TO 20000 PSI &amp; 450 DEGF. LENGTH 48.4 IN., WEIGHT 30.4 LBS." Ship_Weight="0.00" Textbox47="No" />
           <Details2 Asset_Code="EQF-38" Serial_No1="GB3802" Remarks1="1-11/16 IN. DIA STEEL WEIGHT BAR, STD SERVICE. RATED TO 20000 PSI &amp; 450 DEGF. LENGTH 48.4 IN., WEIGHT 30.4 LBS." Ship_Weight="0.00" Textbox47="No" />
           <Details2 Asset_Code="COL-TRX" Serial_No1="4702904" Remarks1="8 RING COLLECTOR, MADE BY TROLEX (third party) generally used in the North sea. Old FCC Part &lt;NA&gt;" Textbox47="No" />
           <Details2 Asset_Code="WPSA-BA" Serial_No1="153" Remarks1="1-11/16&quot; Wireline Perforating Shock Absorber (WPSA-BA)" Textbox47="No" />
           <Details2 Asset_Code="PEH-EFA" Serial_No1="2528" Remarks1="PEH-EFA, HEAD, 1-3/8 FOR FLEX Weak Point" Ship_Weight="0.00" Textbox47="No" />
           <Details2 Asset_Code="PEH-EFA" Serial_No1="2535" Remarks1="PEH-EFA, HEAD, 1-3/8 FOR FLEX Weak Point" Ship_Weight="0.00" Textbox47="No" />
         </Details2_Collection>
       </Tablix3>
     </Details1>
   </Details1_Collection>
 </Tablix2>
</Report>
```

Header part of my file goes like this

```
Dim RITEmanifest As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set RITEmanifest = New DOMDocument
RITEmanifest.async = False
RITEmanifest.Load("path to file")
RITEmanifest.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

So now I can browse through nodes the „hard-coded” way without any problems

```
For Each node In RITEmanifest.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes
    Debug.Print node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Serial_No").value
Next
```

But using SelectNodes does not return any nodes

```
Debug.Print RITEmanifest.SelectNodes("Details").Length
```

Any idea why would that be?

Comment: Would ```RITEmanifest.getElementsByTagName("Details")``` work for you? Or have a look here how to use namspaces in xpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047044/excel-vba-getting-specific-node-from-xml