# Remove the root tag of the XML but keep the contents inside it

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am using the below code to enable the user to select an XML file, and then the code deletes the `<metadata>` tag from the XML, and replaces it by the modified one;

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, doc As Object
    Dim data As Object, filename As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' select file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    ' read file and add top level
    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpentextFile(filename)
    doc.LoadXML Replace(ts.readall, "<metadata>", "<root><metadata>", 1, 1) & "</root>" '<metadata> removed
    ts.Close
    
    ' import data tag only
    Dim s As String
    Set data = doc.getElementsByTagName("data")(0)
    s = data.XML
    ' MsgBox s
    
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(filename, True)
    ts.Write s
    ts.Close
    
    MsgBox s 'works perfectly
End Sub
```

The above code worked perfectly for me, when I was assigned to work with an XML like this -
[image]

But now, I have a different XML to deal with, which is like - (difference : the `ajson` root tag)

[image]

How do I delete the `ajson` opening and closing tags, so I get my desired result? Kindly guide... Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit and show your code attempt that wasn't working.

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu! I haven't tried anything related to deleting the root tag (`ajson`) yet, as I do not know what to search for or what command to use - Kindly guide ... Thanks!

Comment: The new XML has a default namespace so this is possibly related to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047044/excel-vba-getting-specific-node-from-xml).

Comment: Please edit your question, and add your input XML file as a text.

Comment: Are you open to do it via XSLT transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it via XSLT transformation.

XSLT in VBA: [Excel VBA Coding for xls transformation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba46717f-66ee-46fd-a7eb-df4de17d9371/excel-vba-coding-for-xls-transformation)

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ajson:json xmlns:ajson="http://www.google.com">
    <metadata>
        <sample>Hi</sample>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <catalog>
            <book id="bk101">
                <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
                <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
            </book>
        </catalog>
    </data>
</ajson:json>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ajson="http://www.google.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- template to copy without a namespace-->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to remove document's root element -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="metadata">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<data>
  <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    </book>
  </catalog>
</data>
```

Comment: Nice & very instructive to study some variations of identity transforms via XSLT to omit/delete xml declaration, namespaces & specified node(s) - maybe worth some further explanations to not so experienced users. - Couple of notes to cited link: a) Sonal correctly used late binding; so using early b. I would prefer library reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" as latest version after v3.0; b) in all probability the export file name won't get a html extension. @YitzhakKhabinsky

Comment: @T.M. The OP never responded on my suggestion to implement it via XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Since your XML format seems to be variable maybe a simple text processing script is all you need.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, filename As String
    Dim s As String, sOut As String, bData As Boolean
    
    'select file
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        filename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpentextFile(filename)
   
    ' capture between <data> .... </data>
    Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
        s = ts.readline
        If Trim(s) = "<data>" Then bData = True
        If bData Then sOut = sOut & s & vbCrLf
        If Trim(s) = "</data>" Then bData = False
    Loop
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(filename, True)
    ts.Write sOut
    ts.Close
    MsgBox sOut
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do that in VBA using the MSXML objects :

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim myDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    myDoc.LoadXML Sheet1.[A1].Value
    'myDoc now contains the example XML from your post
    Set myDoc = SetNewRoot(myDoc, "data")
    'MyDoc's root has now changed to data, all other nodes & elements are discarded.
End Sub

Function SetNewRoot(XMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, TagName As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim nodeSelect As IXMLDOMSelection
    Set nodeSelect = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(TagName)
    If nodeSelect.Length = 0 Then
        Set SetNewRoot = Nothing
    Else
        Dim newRoot As IXMLDOMNode
        Set newRoot = nodeSelect(0).CloneNode(deep:=True)
        newDoc.appendChild newRoot
        Set SetNewRoot = newDoc
    End If
End Function
```

This code uses the Microsoft XML, v6.0 reference, add that to your project to be able to use these objects. To add the reference automatically, use the following code:

```vb
Private Sub AddXMLRef()
    AddExcelRef ThisWorkbook, "{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}", "MSXML2"
End Sub
Private Sub AddExcelRef(wbk As Workbook, sGuid As String, sRefName As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error GoTo EH
    With wbk.VBProject.References
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Item(i).Name = sRefName Then
               Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If i > .Count Then
           .AddFromGuid sGuid, 0, 0 ' 0,0 should pick the latest version installed on the computer
        End If
    End With
Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Error in 'AddRef'" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: The XMLDom version now; think user Sonal will have to learn a lot today +:)